# How do I format my oracle queries so the columns don't wrap?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
col * format a20000
```

Do I really have to list every column specifically?  That is a huge pain in the arse.

Comment: Props for getting away with using an expletive in a popular question for 10 years!

Answer (score 41):

Never mind, figured it out:

```
set wrap off
set linesize 3000 -- (or to a sufficiently large value to hold your results page)
```

Which I found by:

```
show all
```

And looking for some option that seemed relevant.

Comment: cool, didn't know that one.  I spend most of my time in Toad though.

Comment: Scratch that, wrap set to off does disable the wrap.  But now the line is being truncated.  $%*!

Comment: Okay, figured this out (again):

    set wrap off
    set linesize 3000    // or something very large

Ugh.

Comment: @someguy, you should edit your answer above to include the correct syntax

Answer (score 26):

I use a generic query I call "dump" (why? I don't know) that looks like this:

```
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET LINESIZE 16000
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET COLSEP |

spool &1..txt

@@&1

spool off
exit
```

I then call SQL*Plus passing the actual SQL script I want to run as an argument:

```
sqlplus -S user/password@database @dump.sql my_real_query.sql
```

The result is written to a file

> `my_real_query.sql.txt`

.

Comment: To include the column header I'm using the following setting for PAGESIZE -> `SET PAGESIZE 0 EMBEDDED ON`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
set WRAP OFF
set PAGESIZE 0
```

Try using those settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
set linesize 3000

set wrap off

set termout off

set pagesize 0 embedded on

set trimspool on
```

Try with all above values.