# unable to export columns in single line in csv

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, sql-scripts

i am using sqlplus and trying to export the columns(nearly 250 columns) of table_x. sharing the piece of code below:-

```
SET COLSEP ',' LINESIZE 32767 NUMWIDTH 18 LONG 4000 FEEDBACK OFF ECHO OFF 
SET TRIMOUT ON ARRAYSIZE 5000 AUTOCOMMIT OFF FLUSH OFF HEADING ON TERMOUT OFF
SET PAUSE OFF SERVEROUTPUT ON TRIMSPOOL ON VERIFY OFF
SET UNDERLINE OFF PAGESIZE 50000 ESCAPE OFF
SET HEADING OFF FEEDBACK OFF
spool &spooldrive.&spooldir.table_x.csv
 select /*csv*/
 rtrim(xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(c,column_name||',').EXTRACT('//text()') 
 ORDER BY column_id).GetClobVal(),',') 
 FROM user_tab_cols where table_name = upper('table_x');
spool off;
```

and my output is like this :-

```
column1,column2,column3,colum
n4,column5,column6,column7,co
lumn8,column9...
```

seems like i am missing something. Any pointers ?

Edit1:
when i add
SET WRAP OFF
my output in csv file is like:-

```
column1,column2,column3,colum (yes i get only 4 columns)
```

Edit2:
when, in the same script,i use:

```
select xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(e,column_name||',').EXTRACT('//text()')
 ORDER BY column_id) 
 FROM user_tab_cols where table_name = upper('table_x');
```

i get columns equal to buffer length(4000).
Its clear that if the output from the query is larger than 4000 bytes, it wont be returned. Is there any other way to get full output(even more than max line size limit 4000) just like it is done in sql developer when export into csv??

Comment: Perhaps you just need to set wrap off (among a few other settings)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188118/how-do-i-format-my-oracle-queries-so-the-columns-dont-wrap possibly in conjunction with: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54149/how-to-make-sqlplus-output-appear-in-one-line

Comment: i tried wrap off, but it didn't solve the multiple line output.

Comment: How wide is the real column when it wraps; and where are you looking at the results? Could they just be wrapping in your terminal or editor?

Comment: Alex, i am dealing with a table having 250+ rows. And i am looking the output in csv file 'table_x.csv'. As u asked about wrapping in terminal, i  run query & printed on terminal and found the output in multiple lines, WRAP ON/OFF doesn't affect the output.